# Is asking a question like "is it bad practice to do this rather than this in code" a bad question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question I'd like to post to Stack Overflow, but don't know if it would be right. I want to ask like so: *if I use this code (provide code) versus this code (provide code) is it wrong or bad practice and why?* I posted one formatted similar earlier this weak and it got downvoted, and I took it down because the only response was a critique on my grammar.

Comment: This is a type of "Best practice" question that have been closed due to being "not constructive" or "not a real question". 
Despite understanding the important specifics of your situation and looking for a hard to find solution that was not described before. The specifics of any situation could be really described with additional ways of explanation.

Comment: If by _took it down_ you mean you deleted it, be carefull: too many poorly received and/or deleted questions will lead to a question ban.  Better to undelete it and improve it.

Comment: Can you post the full question here? Maybe someone can help you make it more appropriate/less likely to be downvoted?

Comment: SX have a specialized site for such questions. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more suitable for that kind of questions. 
For SO, *opinion based* would be a practical closure reason.You better try to improve it and try to fit it in a form that community would not mind closing. But I am not sure if it is easy in your condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with such questions is there is no one true "best practice" and  "bad practice" may mean different things to different people.  These questions usually end up as not practically answerable and would only be a collection of various opinions of users not based on facts.

These aren't bad questions per say, but the Q&A format of Stack Exchange does not lend itself well to these types of questions, so they usually will get closed.

And just a side note

> and I took it down because the only response was a critique on my grammar.

Since you don't have a question on SO in your profile, I'm guessing "took it down" means deleted, and since you have the peer pressure badge, I'm guessing that post either had a -3 or worse, or you deleted additional questions that had a -3.  My advise is to watch yourself.  There is an automated question ban that takes into account all of your posts, including deleted posts.  Too many poorly received posts and you can be banned from asking new questions.  1 questions is not going to be a problem, but if you have 3 or 4 bad questions that receive a number of downvotes without some good quality content mixed in, it starts to become a concern.

Comment: On a side note, coming here to discuss it and find out more is a great positive step and learning experience on how the site works.

Comment: I had been banned before and thats why i wrote this. i had asked questions and got downvoted and it got deleted automatically. i had copy and pasted my question i reposted the question and i got wonderful responces(... until it got deleted again) im guessing the site checks if question are asked again after deletion because it was the exact same working)then i got banned this is a new account i dont wanna get banned though so i thought id check

Comment: @Snymax this is a very general answer because you really didn't provide a frame of reference.  It doesn't apply to everything, and your question may be fixable.  "ben is uǝq backwards" asked you above to provide the text of the full question.  Why don't you do that.

Comment: I understand here an example: "my sqlite Driver on my android app database doesn't support the function I need? however I figured out this workaround[...provided code] but im worried I am handling too much client side is this wrong if so can someone show me what to do or where to look?" I see similar questions get downvoted where sometimes the question is opinion bases but based on the guys research i think its better to tell him that its a matter of opinion then downvote him and risk him getting banned for wanting to do something right however your are absolutely right this is too vague.

Comment: @Snymax edit it into your question